# Changing output text for dice rolls

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I am trying to code digital dice that outputs something like this:

> 1: 1 of 36 Rolls  2.7777%
>
> 2: 2 of 36 Rolls  5.5555%
>
> 3: 3 of 36 Rolls  8.3333%

Not quite sure how to do that but this is the code I have.

```
import random 
import colorama 

from colorama import Fore, Style 

random.seed()

ROLLED = {i: 0 for i in range(1, 7)}
ITERATIONS = int(input(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + "How many times would you like to roll the dice?\n"))

Style.RESET_ALL

def probability():
    print(Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX+"Calculation of probability:")
    for key, count in ROLLED.items():
        print("\t{}: {:.2f}".format(key, count*100./ITERATIONS*1.))


for _ in range(ITERATIONS):#for the inputted range for the iterations
    ROLLED[random.randint(1, 6)] += 1

probability()
```

I don't know how to do that. could use help/tips to find out.

Comment: What does this do right now? Also you haven't imported `random`, so this won't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the for loop in which you are rolling to this:

```
for roll in range(1,ITERATIONS+1):
    ROLLED[random.randint(1, 6)] += 1
    print("{} of {} Rolls {}%".format(roll,ITERATIONS,round(100/ITERATIONS*roll,4)))
```

Also don't forget to `import random` somewhere

## Output

```
How many times would you like to roll the dice?
36
1 of 36 Rolls 2.7778%
2 of 36 Rolls 5.5556%
3 of 36 Rolls 8.3333%
4 of 36 Rolls 11.1111%
5 of 36 Rolls 13.8889%
6 of 36 Rolls 16.6667%
7 of 36 Rolls 19.4444%
8 of 36 Rolls 22.2222%
9 of 36 Rolls 25.0%
10 of 36 Rolls 27.7778%
11 of 36 Rolls 30.5556%
12 of 36 Rolls 33.3333%
13 of 36 Rolls 36.1111%
14 of 36 Rolls 38.8889%
15 of 36 Rolls 41.6667%
16 of 36 Rolls 44.4444%
17 of 36 Rolls 47.2222%
18 of 36 Rolls 50.0%
19 of 36 Rolls 52.7778%
20 of 36 Rolls 55.5556%
21 of 36 Rolls 58.3333%
22 of 36 Rolls 61.1111%
23 of 36 Rolls 63.8889%
24 of 36 Rolls 66.6667%
25 of 36 Rolls 69.4444%
26 of 36 Rolls 72.2222%
27 of 36 Rolls 75.0%
28 of 36 Rolls 77.7778%
29 of 36 Rolls 80.5556%
30 of 36 Rolls 83.3333%
31 of 36 Rolls 86.1111%
32 of 36 Rolls 88.8889%
33 of 36 Rolls 91.6667%
34 of 36 Rolls 94.4444%
35 of 36 Rolls 97.2222%
36 of 36 Rolls 100.0%
Calculation of probability:
    1: 13.89
    2: 22.22
    3: 13.89
    4: 22.22
    5: 11.11
    6: 16.67
```

**As additional info:**

Because you are using python 3 the `/` is a "normal" division. Basically: `5/2 = 2.5` while `//`is the integer division: `5//2 = 2`

So you can change `count*100./ITERATIONS*1.` to `count*100/ITERATIONS` without the float casting magic.